# Create Service account using Jenkins on any server

Tags: jenkins

I want to pull the code from repository(read access only) to deploy the project.
For that Can anyone Explain how to create and connect Service account in Jenkins on Linux or any server.

I am expecting the detailed explanation on Service account on Jenkins

Comment: Might be not enough details to provide an answer